# Ballerina Composer Try-it requests 404 but OK from external cURL or Chrome

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-composer

I'm trying the Composer examples on the welcome page and when I run them, the request is 404 in the Try-it tab but if I use cURL from iTerm or a browser to the same URL, it works fine. I can run the same examples fine from VS Code as well.

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks, Phil

Comment: Did you run using the composer's run command in the Run menu and then use the Tryit?

Comment: what's the URL you cURL?

Comment: Yes @RiyafaAbdulHameed, sorry if I wasn't clear. My point is that _after_ running it, the Try-it Send URL fails but if I copy it into a browser, it works fine

Comment: @pahan I copy this URL from the Try-it pane `http://localhost:9091/hello/sayHello` (where if I press Send I get 404) and paste it into a browser "Hello, Ballerina"

Comment: PS I shifted the port to 9091 in the service so that's not the issue, I can revert it and the problem is still the same:
in VS Code Terminal:
```ballerina: initiating service(s) in 'hello_service.bal
ballerina: started HTTP/WS endpoint 0.0.0.0:9090```
then in another Terminal window:
```CWD:ballerina Phil$ curl http://localhost:9090/hello/sayHello
Hello Ballerina!```

Comment: @user192108 Seems this is a bug in composer. can you share the version you are using and operating system?

Comment: @user192108 I tested this on ballerina 0.981 distribution and could not reproduce the issue.